# Find the number of solution to this hyperbolic equation.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $m \in \mathbb{R}$.
I want to find the number of solution of

$$x (\cosh(x) -1) - m \sinh(x) = 0.$$

I already know that for $m< 0$ there is only one solution at $x=0$ (just study the sign of the deritative).

For $m=0$ there are two obvious solutions. **Edit : Only one as $\cosh(x) = 1 \iff x=0$.**

Yet I am struggling with $m>0$, does anyone have any clue on how to proceed ? (I also know from plotting the function that I expect three
solutions at $0$, $\alpha$, $-\alpha$).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You know that there is only one solution if $m> 0$, but you are struggling with the case $m > 0$?

Comment: Sorry, it's been changed accordingly !

Comment: My first impression is that it is exactly the other way around: For $m < 0$ the function is strictly increasing and there is only one solution.

Comment: Sorry I mixed up the sign. The case $m<0$ is the easy one with a strictly increasing function. I am now looking to the case $m>0$.

Comment: There is one solution for $m=0$, not two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x\ne0,$ the equation is equivalent to
$$x\tanh\frac x2=m.$$
[The function $x\mapsto x\tanh\frac x2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+x+tanh%28x%2F2%29) is even, and maps bijectively $[0,+\infty)$ onto itself (its derivative is easily seen to be $>0$ on $(0,+\infty)$).

Comment: Very clever! – I have posted my (more complicated) solution anyway, because it demonstrates some general techniques.

Comment: Thank you both of you for your help =)

Answer (score 1):

Let us investigate the function
$$
 f(x) = x (\cosh(x) - 1) - m \sinh(x) 
$$
for $m > 0$. Because of the symmetry $f(-x) = -f(x)$ is suffices to consider the case $x \ge 0$.

We have $f(0) = 0$, $f'(0) = -m < 0$ and $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty$, which implies that $f(x) = 0$ has a smallest strictly positive solution $a$.

Now we use that
$$
 f''(x) - f(x) = x + 2 \sinh(x)
$$
is strictly positive for all $x > 0$. If $f(x) = 0$ has another solution $b > a$ then $f$ has a non-negative maximum at some point $x^* \in (0, b)$. But that is not possible because
$$
 f''(x^*) > f(x^*) \ge 0 
$$
and the second derivative is $\le 0$ at a local maximum.

This shows that $f(x) = 0$ has exactly one positive $a$ solution if $m > 0$. Because of the symmetry of $f$ that makes three real solutions $-a, 0, a$ in total.